# Can I retain ownership of QObjects passed to QJSEngine?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qjsengine

I'm using QJSEngine and binding some objects with `engine.globalObject().setProperty(name, engine.newQObject(obj));`

The problem is that QJSEngine destructor is calling the destructors of those objects but I want them to outlive the QJSEngine object.

This happens even if I remove the property from globalObject().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like using QQmlEngine instead of QJSEngine gives access to `setObjectOwnership` which allows to work around the issue.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#setObjectOwnership

From what I understand from the docs though, it will still be an issue with objects returned from Q_INVOKABLE methods, which I'm not sure how to retain ownership of. So if anyone has some ideas, I'd like to know them.

Comment: This is actually not an issue for objects returned from Q_INVOKABLEs, the QML engine won't take ownership of them if you called `setObjectOwnership` with `CppOwnership` or if they have a parent QObject.

Comment: `QQmlEngine::setObjectOwnership(QObject *object, QQmlEngine::ObjectOwnership ownership)` is static. Thus, it should also work with QJSEngine objects as well